# security on two tables Symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony, service

I'm using Symfony 2.3 and I can't find a good solution to add a security on two tables.

I have an user and this user can get an application, he can access to his application with this path: /application/{id}

So I'd like to secure this page if the user is link to the application. I do something to check in my controller but this not very clean:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param int $idApplication
 * @return UserApplication
 */
public function testUserApplication($idApplication){

    //get the application
    $applicationRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PhoneApplicationBundle:Application');
    $application = $applicationRepository->find($idApplication);

    if($application==null){
        return null;
    }

    $userApplicationRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PhoneApplicationBundle:UserApplication');
    $userApplication = $userApplicationRepository->findOneBy(array(
            'user' => $this->getUser(),
            'application' => $application
    ));

    return $userApplication;
}
```

I don't know if I can do this using the security.

I try an other solution creating a service which check this

```
class Test
{

/** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
private $doctrine;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param Doctrine        $doctrine
 */
public function __construct(Doctrine $doctrine)
{
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
}

public function userApplication($idApplication){

    //get the application
    $applicationRepository = $this->doctrine->getRepository('PhoneApplicationBundle:Application');
    $application = $applicationRepository->find($idApplication);

    if($application==null){
        return null;
    }

    $userApplicationRepository = $this->doctrine->getRepository('PhoneApplicationBundle:UserApplication');
    $userApplication = $userApplicationRepository->findOneBy(array(
            'user' => $this->getUser(),
            'application' => $application
    ));

    return $userApplication;
}

}
```

service.yml:

```
parameters:
    phone_application.test_user_application.class: Phone\ApplicationBundle\Service\Test

services:
    phone_application.test_user_application:
        class: %phone_application.test_user_application.class%
        arguments: [@doctrine]
```

But I don't realy understand how to use this in a controller

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**

If you want to use a service in your controller, do

```
$serv = $this->get('nameoftheservice);
//then 
$serv->yourFunctionOfTheService();
```

In your case :

```
$serv = $this->get('phone_application.test_user_application');
//then 
$serv->userApplication($id);
```

**Second**

Another way to do it :

If the `$user` object is fully available in your controller just do :

```
//get the app
$application = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PhoneApplicationBundle:Application')->find($idApplication);

//check if this user owns this app, considering you have sets the right doctrine annotation for relation in your entity file
if($user->getApplications()->contains($application)) {
    //do your stuff
}
else
    throw new \Exception('No right there ! ');
```